# maps undefined but still prints to console

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

Trying to get google maps working in my react app.

Here is my Map.jsx component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import key from '../key';

class Map extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    let script = document.createElement('script')

    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${key.API_KEY}&callback=initMap`);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

    window.initMap = () => {
      console.log('initMap');
      console.log(google);
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const mapStyle = {
      height: "400px",
      width: "100%"
    };

    return <div ref="map" style={mapStyle} />;
  }

}

export default Map;
```

and index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Match } from 'react-router';
import GoogleMapsLoader from 'google-maps';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.css';

import App from './App';
import StakeCreator from './components/StakeCreator';

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Match exactly pattern="/" component={StakeCreator} />
        <Match pattern="/stake/:stakeId" component={App} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
GoogleMapsLoader.load(function(google) {
    render(
        <Root />,
       document.getElementById('root')
    );
})
```

What's really unusual is both console.logs print. But I still get an

> error  'google' is not defined

[image]

I do notice the error is coming from `webpackHotDevClient`

There is a big issue on github about it

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2145

but there doesn't appear to be a clear fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got your fix right here... first off, handle the API key in `index.js` like so:

```
import key from './key.js'
GoogleMapsLoader.KEY = key.API_KEY
```

then in `Map.jsx`, set your `componentDidMount()` like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let google = window.google
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
      center: {lat: 33.7065883 , lng: -117.9818307},
      zoom: 8 //YOU HAVE TO SET A ZOOM LEVEL
    })
}
```

it works for me, I've got the map showing, looks great!

Comment: @TylerZika glad I could help. It was fun, good luck on your project!